# differential equation on straight lines

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the differential equation of straight lines with algebraic sum of the intercepts fixed as k?
answer: $(xy'-y)(y'-1)+ky'=0$
but I need the solution. help me out please

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: You are looking for a differential equation whose solutions are lines whose x and y intersepts sum up to $k$?

Answer (score 1):

You may know that, among the different ways to write the equation of a straight line, one of them is :

$$\tag{1}\dfrac{x}{x_0}+\dfrac{y}{y_0}=1$$

where $x_0$ is the abscissa of the intercept with the $x$ axis, and $y_0$ is the ordinate of the intercept with the $y$ axis.

(check for example that if $y=y_0$ then $x=0$ ; the same thing when $x=x_0$).

Then, as $x_0+y_0=k$, one may write (1) under the form:

$$\tag{2}\dfrac{x}{k-y_0}+\dfrac{y}{y_0}=1 \ \iff \ y = y_0(1 - \dfrac{x}{k-y_0})  \ \iff \ $$

$$\tag{3}y =  \left(\dfrac{y_0}{y_0-k}\right)x+y_0$$

which depends on the single parameter $x_0$.

Now, if, in the left hand side of differential equation

$$\tag{4} \ (xy'-y)(y'-1)+ky'=0$$

we replace $y$ by (3) and $y'$ by $\left(\dfrac{y_0}{y_0-k}\right)$, it is easy to check that we obtain a right hand side in (4) which is $0$ (variable $y_0$ vanishes in the computation).

In a converse way, one could ask whether all solutions of the given differential equation are straight lines with equation (3).